# Parametrising the surface $x^2+z^2 = y^3(1-y)^3$

Tags: surfaces, parametrization

I am working on the following exercise:

> Consider the surface given by the equation $x^2+z^2 = y^3(1-y)^3$. Where can a parametrisation $z(x,y)$ be introduced? Calculate $\partial z / \partial_x$ and $\partial z / \partial_y$.
>
> REMARK: I found out that the surface looks like this here:
>
> https://imaginary.org/gallery/herwig-hauser-classic

I reorded the equation to:
$$z^2 = y^3(1-y)^3-x^2$$
, which implies

$$z = \pm\sqrt{y^3(1-y)^3-x^2}$$

So I think a parametrisation of the surface by $z(x,y)$ is not possible, every point $(x,y)$ gets mapped to two different $z$ unless $y^3(1-y)^3-x^2 = 0.$ Is there something I am missing in here?

Comment: Not sure what the sentence "Where can a parametrisation $z(x, y)$ be introduced?" means: by restricting $z > 0$ say, then you can choose the $+$ sign in your formula and get a parametrisation?

Comment: I suppose it is meant in the way that you can not just restrict to one sign for the root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you are missing nothing. For each $(x,y,z)$ in your surface, $(x,y,-z)$ belongs to the surface too. And both points have the same first and second coordinates. So, unless $z=0$, there are two points of the surface with the same first and second coordinates and therefore your surface is not of the form$$\left\{\bigl(x,y,z(x,y)\bigr)\,\middle|\,(x,y)\in D\right\}.$$for some subset $D$ of $\mathbb R^2$ and some function $z\colon D\longrightarrow\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 2):

One can parameterize
$$
x^2+z^2=y^3(1-y)^3
$$
on $[0,1]^2$ as
$$
\left((t(1-t))^{3/2}\cos(2\pi s),\,t,\,(t(1-t))^{3/2}\sin(2\pi s)\right)
$$
As given, the radius in the $y=\frac12$ plane is $\frac18$:

[image]

However, as with a lot of orientable, closed surfaces, almost all lines that intersect the surface (entering the interior) will intersect the surface again (exiting the interior). Thus, the lines for most $x$ and $y$ will intersect the surface at more than one point. This prevents a complete parameterization of the form $(x,y,z(x,y))$.